# View is not reading session or flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, twitter

Trying to login with twitter. Get the screen_name and set to the session and flashdata. When I try to access the session data on view again, I don't get anything.
**View**

```
<div class="logged-in-user offset9" id="user-navbar" >
            <img class="img-circle" style="height:46px; width:46px;" src=""/>
            <a href="./getting-started.html"><?php $this->session->flashdata('twitter_screen_name');?></a>
          </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller**
I do get the screen name in the log message.

```
$access_token = $this->connection->getAccessToken($this->input->get('oauth_verifier'));

            if ($this->connection->http_code == 200)
            {

                $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $access_token['oauth_token']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('access_token_secret', $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_user_id', $access_token['user_id']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_screen_name', $access_token['screen_name']);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('twitter_screen_name', $access_token['screen_name']);
                $this->session->unset_userdata('request_token');
                $this->session->unset_userdata('request_token_secret');
                log_message('info','>>>>>>>>>>>Enter Twitter Login'.$this->session->userdata('twitter_screen_name'));
                redirect(base_url('/'));


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed echo

instead of

```
<?php $this->session->flashdata('twitter_screen_name');?>
```

write

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('twitter_screen_name');?>
```